# Unexpected call to method or property access in IE7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var span = $("*:contains('uniqueText')");
    $(span).text("newText");
})
```

My jQuery version is v1.11.0;

`var span` is a `<span>` element;

This code works under Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE9/10/11.

**The problem** comes in IE7/8, where the exception is thrown on the line where the `.text` method is called.

I found a lot of "solutions" but none worked for me.

What I tried:

- `.text()` method,
- `.html()` method,
- I tried this: `$(span)[0].innerText = "newText";`

Nothing seemed to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: please always provide examples like this as a JSFiddle with sample HTML (saves everyone loads of typing) :) (Except in this case JSFiddle does not work with IE 7 & 8) :>

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on your code snippet `;` at `})` but I guess you're aware.. ;-)

Comment: `var span is a <span> element;` so why do you have a `*` all selector in your jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

*`var span` is a `<span>` element;*

If this is the case then you can try with this:

```
var span = $("span:contains('uniqueText')");
```

because `*` is very bad to use it will look-up the whole dom instead of specific tag.

I don't recommend this but you can try this also:

```
 var span = $("body *:contains('uniqueText')");
```